# fillna for string to "", for number to -1 for passing table as json

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_margin=pd.DataFrame({"item":["a","b","c",np.nan],"margin":[3,4,5,np.nan]})
```

Given table below from above code, I want to fillna for string to "", for number to -1, how to do it automatically assume I have lot of columns?

```
  item  margin
0    a     3.0
1    b     4.0
2    c     5.0
3  NaN     NaN
```

df_margin=pd.DataFrame({"item":["a","b","c",""],"margin":[3,4,5,-1]})
desired outcome

```
  item  margin
0    a       3
1    b       4
2    c       5
3           -1
```

Reason is that I want to pass the table as json, but it can't support nan value, better method are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`dtype.kind`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) with `apply` method to get the result you desired.

### Method One:

```
>>> df_margin.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(-1) if x.dtype.kind in 'biufcSUV' else x.fillna(''))
  item  margin
0    a     3.0
1    b     4.0
2    c     5.0
3         -1.0
```

*Note: To know more about `'biufcSUV'` please read the `dtype.kind`*

### Explanation from the Doc:

```
dtype.kind
A character code (one of ‘biufcOSUV’) identifying the general kind of data.

b   boolean
i   signed integer
u   unsigned integer
f   floating-point
c   complex floating-point
O   object
S   (byte-)string
U   Unicode
V   void
```

### Method Two:

This method i see more elegant.

```
df_margin.fillna({'item':'', 'margin':'-1'})
# df_margin.fillna({'item':'', 'margin':'-1'}, inplace=True)
  item margin
0    a      3
1    b      4
2    c      5
3          -1
```

### Method Three:

```
df_margin['item'] = df_margin.select_dtypes("object").fillna("")
df_margin['margin'] = df_margin.select_dtypes("float64").fillna("-1")

df_margin
  item margin
0    a      3
1    b      4
2    c      5
3          -1
```

OR

```
df_margin.fillna(df_margin.dtypes.replace({'float64': -1, 'object': ''}))
  item  margin
0    a     3.0
1    b     4.0
2    c     5.0
3         -1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

for strings

```
df_margin[df_margin.select_dtypes('object').columns] = df_margin.select_dtypes('object').fillna(' ')
```

for numbers

```
df_margin[df_margin.select_dtypes('number').columns] = df_margin.select_dtypes('number').fillna(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter the dataframe via [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and then `fill` `NaN` with required values:

```
df_margin[df_margin.select_dtypes('object').columns] = df_margin.select_dtypes('object').fillna('')
df_margin[df_margin.select_dtypes('number').columns] = df_margin.select_dtypes('number').fillna(-1)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
  item  margin
0    a     3.0
1    b     4.0
2    c     5.0
3         -1.0
```

*NOTE:*

1. You can further explore different values for `(include=None, exclude=None)`
2. I'll suggest using a mapping dictionary (object_type/fill_value). If you want to have more fine-grain control.